# Returning Observable for each item in a List in Asynchronous Callback

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have tried using "Observable.create" for getting async callbacks, but the observable is not waiting for each item emitted to complete its download in  **emitter.onNext** .

```java
getListA()   
.flatMap(aList -> {
    int total = aList.size();
    return Observable.fromIterable(aList)
        .flatMap(a -> Observable.create(emitter -> {
            // ----------------------------------------------
            AsyncDownloader
            .download(remoteUrl, filePath, fileName)
            .build()
            .setOnStartOrResumeListener(() -> {
                 Timber.d("Download Start Thread ==>  %s", Thread.currentThread());
            })
            .setOnProgressListener(progress -> {
                 int progressPercent = (int) 
                     (progress.currentBytes * 100 / progress.totalBytes);
                 mView.onDownloadProgress(
                     progressPercent, progress.currentBytes,
                     progress.totalBytes, fileName, 
                     total, currentFileCount);
            })
            .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onDownloadComplete() {
                     emitter.onNext(a);
                     emitter.onComplete();
                     currentFileCount++;
                 }
                 @Override
                 public void onError(Error error) {

                 }
            });
            //-----------------------------------------------------
        }));
        .toList()
        .toObservable();
})
```

The issue is that , for each A emitted from **Observable.fromIterable()** , **emitter.onNext** is not called and made to wait for completion ..instead all the items are emmitted before the **AsyncDownloader** completes..and then **emitter.OnNext** is called!!

**I want like the Download to complete and then call the  Next Item from the list..  **

..Is the approach wrong..Kindly help!

Comment: What exactly is emitted before the AsyncDownloader finises? How can it emit something, if this thing is not even available yet?

Comment: @Bal0r..Hi...actually **emitter.OnNext(a)** is called after all the list items has been iterated and does not wait for **emitter.OnComplete()**  before the another item is emitted from **Observable.fromIterable(listA)**..  ie) i want each iteration from A List to call **emitter.OnComplete** before the next iteration.Hope i am clear now!!!

Comment: Use `concatMap` instead of `flatMap`.

Comment: @akarnokd...thanks for the help.. **concatMap** solves the issue..!!